# Why is $\Gamma (A)$ closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a commutative $C^\ast$ algebra and let $\Gamma: A \to C_0(\Omega (A))$ be the map $a \mapsto \widehat{a}$. Here $\Omega(A)$ denotes the character space of $A$.

Why is $\Gamma (A)$ closed in $C_0 (\Omega (A))$?

Comment: In order to apply tomasz hint, show that $\Gamma$ is isometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: if $M$ is a metric space and $N\subseteq M$ is complete with subspace metric, then $N$ is closed in $M$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it before but of course a linear surjective isometry is a homeomorphism.